# ROS2: node vs managed node

Tags: ros, ros2, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm starting to port a node from ROS1 to ROS2 (ardent).
One of the novelty that seems more promising in ROS2 is the `lifecycle` of the nodes, but I cannot find a complete examples if not the [lifecycle demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/lifecycle).

All the ROS drivers that I found on Github do not use the "managed node" interface, but they are simply created as ROS1 nodes with the only difference that they are derived from `rclcpp::Node`.

What really concerns me is how to manage a "managed node"... is there a node to control the status of it?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301844/ros2:-node-vs-managed-node/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-08-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-28**:
Any particular reason for using ardent instead of bouncy?

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-29**:
Because it is not yet available as debian installer under Ubuntu 16.04.
I'm not migrating to Ubuntu 18.04 since I'm using also the Jetson TX2 and the latest Jetpack is still based on 16.04

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-29**:
However today I tried to manage the NODE using CLI service calls and I can correctly change state.
One thing I expected was that after calling a Shutdown the node closed, instead it remains in "finalized" state and the only way to kill it is the standard Ctrl+C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [lifecycle demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/lifecycle) is a fairly complete example. You should also look at the [managed nodes](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Managed-Nodes/) wiki page, which talks about the example and what is going on.

Managed nodes can be controlled using the `ros2 lifecycle` command. Run `ros2 lifecycle -h` to get its help. It's still a little rudimentary - you have to specify a transition as text, rather than being able to say "activate node X", for example. But it does work. But the big thing for managed nodes is that the [new launch system](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Launch-system/) uses them. You will be able to do things like launch all the nodes and only activate them when all nodes are actually ready to run, ensuring you don't get a half-started system.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-29**:
Thank you for the answer. `ros2 lifecycle` is not available with Ardent, but you gave me the reply I was searching for: the launch system.

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2018-08-29**:
you should be able to easily compile the  `ros2 lifecycle` package on top of your ardent workspace.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-29**:
You are right. I'm going to try it